# JQuery Grab Content from Page Anchors and Replace Hover State Titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a set of page anchors that using JQuery are set where the anchor links show a pop-up tool tip to say what the anchor is called.

I want to be able to take the h4 title of the page anchor and replace the `title` of the anchor link using JQuery.

Here is the mark up of the one of the anchors:

```
<a name="section1">
    <h4 id="sectiontitle1">Overview</h4>
</a>
<p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute ocurreret disputando vis te. 
       Has ludus splendide ex, ei mea habemus invidunt voluptatibus, 
       nihil prompta deleniti eu mea. Id has alterum appellantur 
       delicatissimi, an <a href="form.html">vix justo mentitum</a>.Est 
       cu illud nihil. Ei mei iisque accumsan reprimique.
</p>
```

Here are the links to said page anchors:

```
<div class="article-anchors">
    <ul>
     <li class="to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
     <li><a href="#section1" title="section1" class="articleS1">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section2" title="section2" class="articleS2">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section3" title="section3" class="articleS3">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section4" title="section4" class="articleS4">4</a></li>
     <li class="to-bottom"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Script for the solution:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.article-anchors li a').mouseenter(function() {
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).attr('title', $("[name=" + title + "] h4").html());
                $(this).data('tipText', title)
                $('<p class="tool-tip"></p>')
                    .text(title)
                    .appendTo('body')
                    .fadeIn('slow');
            }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var mousex = e.pageX + -130;
                var mousey = e.pageY + -40;
                $('.tool-tip')
                    .css({
                        top: mousey,
                        left: mousex
                    })
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $('.tool-tip').fadeOut();
            });
            $('.to-top').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 700);
            });
            $('.to-bottom').click(function() {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(document).height()
                }, 700);
                return false;
            });
            $('a:contains("section")').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');
        });
```

so the pop ups tool tips when hovering over should show:

1. section 1 = Overview
2. section 2 = Main Structure
3. section 3 = Support
4. section 4 = Contact

   [final UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqapy.png)

what would be the best way to achieve this? I have tried `:contains`, but this has brought me no joy.

TIA.

This is the fiddle for the problem: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rbk5s43h/)

to mention, that the jquery that drives the pop-up tool tip is heavily dependent on the css and doesn't seem to want to play ball, but if you hover over the numbered bullets on the right, the titles show up and need to match the titles of each section, 1 will be overview, 2 will be main structure etc.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it to understand the scenario?

Comment: Can please bit more specific about your problem

Comment: make a fiddle for it

Comment: would a mock up visual help? I can update the issue with a screenshot of the UI Design? would that help @HarshitJain?

Comment: I'll do it now. 2 seconds

Comment: Ok, with the bullet point anchor links being heavily dependent on css, the fiddle doesn't look great, so the best way to describe the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rbk5s43h/) if you hover over the anchors 1,2,3,4, they show the title within the article anchors, they need to match up with the h4 tagged titles in the  article content, which they anchor to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){

  var popupTitle = $('<p class="tool-tip"></p>').appendTo($('body')).hide();

  // Find your links, but we could have generated your links from the client side
  $('div.article-anchors ul li a[href^="#"]').each(function(){
    var ref = $(this),
        anchor = ref.attr('href') || '', // Find the #anchor
        pound = anchor.indexOf('#'); // Find the location of #
    // Verify
    if (pound >= 0 && (pound + 1) < anchor.length) {
      // Remove the # sign
      anchor = anchor.substring(pound + 1);
      // Find and set the title from the first h4 tag
      ref.attr('floatTitle', $('a[name="'+anchor+'"] h4:first').text());
      ref.attr('title', '');
    }
  }).mouseenter(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr('floatTitle');
      popupTitle.stop().hide()
          .text(title)
          .fadeIn('slow');
  }).mousemove(function(e) {
      var mousex = e.pageX + -130;
      var mousey = e.pageY + -40;
      popupTitle
          .css({
              top: mousey,
              left: mousex
          })
  }).mouseout(function() {
      popupTitle.fadeOut();
  });

  $('.to-top').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
      }, 700);
  });
  $('.to-bottom').click(function() {
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(document).height()
      }, 700);
      return false;
  });
  $('a:contains("section")').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');

});
```

```css
/*article anchors*/

.article-anchors {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
}

.article-anchors ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.article-anchors ul li:first-child i,
.article-anchors ul li:last-child i {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 39px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    color: #0485c2;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.article-anchors ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.article-anchors ul li a {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    width: 36px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #E9F2F7;
    border: 3px solid #0485c2;
    color: #0485c2;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.tool-tip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #9EC483;
    background-color: #CFE5BF;
    border: 1px solid #9EC483;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="article-anchors">
    <ul>
     <li class="to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
     <li><a href="#section1" title="section1" class="articleS1">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section2" title="section2" class="articleS2">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section3" title="section3" class="articleS3">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#section4" title="section4" class="articleS4">4</a></li>
     <li class="to-bottom"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a name="section1"><h4 id="sectiontitle1">Overview 1</h4></a>
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute ocurreret disputando vis te. 
   Has ludus splendide ex, ei mea habemus invidunt voluptatibus, 
   nihil prompta deleniti eu mea. Id has alterum appellantur 
   delicatissimi, an <a href="form.html">vix justo mentitum</a>.Est 
   cu illud nihil. Ei mei iisque accumsan reprimique.
</p>
<a name="section2"><h4 id="sectiontitle2">Overview 2</h4></a>
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute ocurreret disputando vis te. 
   Has ludus splendide ex, ei mea habemus invidunt voluptatibus, 
   nihil prompta deleniti eu mea. Id has alterum appellantur 
   delicatissimi, an <a href="form.html">vix justo mentitum</a>.Est 
   cu illud nihil. Ei mei iisque accumsan reprimique.
</p>
<a name="section3"><h4 id="sectiontitle3">Overview 3</h4></a>
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute ocurreret disputando vis te. 
   Has ludus splendide ex, ei mea habemus invidunt voluptatibus, 
   nihil prompta deleniti eu mea. Id has alterum appellantur 
   delicatissimi, an <a href="form.html">vix justo mentitum</a>.Est 
   cu illud nihil. Ei mei iisque accumsan reprimique.
</p>
<a name="section4"><h4 id="sectiontitle4">Overview 4</h4></a>
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, brute ocurreret disputando vis te. 
   Has ludus splendide ex, ei mea habemus invidunt voluptatibus, 
   nihil prompta deleniti eu mea. Id has alterum appellantur 
   delicatissimi, an <a href="form.html">vix justo mentitum</a>.Est 
   cu illud nihil. Ei mei iisque accumsan reprimique.
</p>
```

**Full-page the snippet to see it better.**

Comment: this is cool, with this solution in place, I am trying to ensure that the "title" has the .tool-tip class applied to it, so that it shows up as a green tool tip instead of the default small white version.

Comment: I integrated the code so it does the fancy green tool-tip.

Comment: perfect solution, thanks for integrating it into my original code, made it much easier to see how the solution works. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mouseenter` function should look like this

```
$('.article-anchors li a').mouseenter(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).attr('title', $("[name="+title +"] h4").html());
})
```

Comment: is there a way we can cater for titles with 2 words. This works for 1, 3 and 4, but where "Main Structure" is concerned, the pop up doesn't appear, also, take into account if we remove reference to ".tool-tip", we have no green tool-tip pop ups. I realise that foolishly, I haven't placed my script up, so I will add it in to the main comment now.

Comment: Change `text` to `.html` for the `.tool-tip` tag